# Proof of an equation in functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a set of size $n$ like $\Omega =\lbrace 1,2,\cdots ,n\rbrace $, where $n$ is a positive integer. For every $x\in P(\Omega )$, define the function $f^x:P(\Omega )\rightarrow \lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace$ as follows:
$$f^x (z) = (-1)^{\vert z-x \vert}$$
where $z-x$ is the difference of $z$ and $x$ in set theory.
Prove the equatuion below:
$$ f^xf^y = f^{x+y+\Omega }$$
where, by $x+y$, we mean the symmetric difference between $x$ and $y$. indeed, $x+y= (x-y)\cup (y-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram as in the following figure. The universe $\Omega$ is partitioned into eight subsets containing $n_k$ elements, as indicated.

[image]

From the figure one can read off, e.g.,
$$|z-x|=n_1+n_5,\quad |z-y|=n_1+n_6\ .$$
Now express $|z-(x+y+\Omega)|$ in terms of the $n_k$, and you are almost there.